# Testing Flask REST server

Tags: python, flask

I have a tiny Flask server that is supposed to load data from a file and run a function on it. This function will return a DataFrame and I return the json version of it. Much to my surprise this all works nicely. However, how would I test this? I have included some attempts below but I don't understand Flask (nor REST) well enough yet:

```
#!/home/thomas/python
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class UniverseAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        import pandas as pd
        frame = pd.read_csv("//datasrv10//data$//AQ//test.csv", index_col=0, header=0)
        return frame.to_json()


api.add_resource(UniverseAPI, '/data/universe')
```

I am happy to include a few of my attempts here... I appreciate any hints. I have read the official documentation.

I should specify what I mean with testing. I can run this on my linux server and can extract all the required information with the requests package. However, I want to create a unittest that comes without the need to start the server on the localhost. I think I have managed with the FLASK test-client. However, the problem now is that the requests response object and the flask response object treat the underlying json strings rather differently. So I guess my problem is more related to json string issues rather than FLASK. Thanks for all your helpful feedback though

Comment: Here is a good start http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/

Answer (score 0):

Well, the basics of writing a REST API are essentially a set of design principles.  My understanding of it is based on this article by Miguel Grinberg, http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask .

In it, he talks about how a REST API is:

- "Stateless" - All interactions with the service can happen using the information from one request.
- Built upon accessing "resources" from URIs using HTTP requests like GET, PUTS, and POST.  A resource could be an order in a store, a task in a web app, or whatever you like.

There's also a bunch of stuff about how the server should standardize all forms of communication between itself and the client, indicate whether it can do cacheing, and other stuff like that.  From an initial design standpoint, though, this is "the point" as he put it:

> "The task of designing a web service or API that adheres to the REST guidelines then becomes > an exercise in identifying the resources that will be exposed and how they will be affected  > by the different request methods."

If you're looking for an interesting example of a REST API that might be suited to your interests (I know it is to mine), reddit's is open source.  It's a relatable example to see how they try and structure the interactions behind requests: http://www.reddit.com/dev/api